# TYPO3 Record List filled with data from REST API

Tags: rest, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I have two server, one is hosting TYPO3, the other is hosting some data and offers a good REST Api.

The data from the REST Service should be editable in TYPO3 Backend.

Can I have the data listed in list module like TYPO3 records? The user/editor should not feel/see any difference to records which are from local extbase Extensions. The records should be editable such as normal TYPO3 records. Also the creation of records should be possible.

I can do that by implementing own model, TCA, sql and so on and holding the data also in TYPO3. (TCA hooks for updating etc.)

But is that possible without holding a full copy of the data in TYPO3?

What would be a good practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your not in haste with this, you can wait for future releases of TYPO3.

In the future the form engine can handle endpoints outside of TYPO3.
So you can use the REST API of magento as an example, to manage product data.
The informations comes right from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o6VP-YD9io&index=2&list=PL-sDBIrOKGOZcad0auYjfb13tB6FscGrv) (minute 32)

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant. But we will go online with TYPO3 8. 
So I will build a model and TCA etc. and implement the REST Stuff in my Repository, right?

Comment: This would be the way to go for now, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TYPO3 8 or greater, you can configure a second database connection to the database of your rest api. See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Configuration/Index.html

In TYPO3 you need to register TCA for this table. The table name must not be the same. You can map this in DB connection. But the cols must be existing and (just a guess) probably the remote table requires an uid column.